# Não consigo recuperar uma lista de objetos Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, collection

Tenho uma duvida que não achei em lugar algum, testei parte e deu certo com duvidas e a outra não deu. Vou explicar, se alguem puder ajudar.

O problema é o seguinte, se eu tenho duas classes chamadas:

Class Aluno{
String key;
String nomeAluno;
String materia_Ref
...
}

Class Materia{
String key; 
String nomeMateria;
List listAlunos;
...
}

Quando eu faço um setValue com um objeto Materia com sua lista de alunos populado ele cria no Firebase Realtime os dados, salva perfeito. Mas na hora de recuperar não estou conseguindo, os dados parecem que não vem!!!

Problema (Fotos) :: Ele cria uma lista de 0 a x dependendo de alunos na lista, mas quando faço por exemplo um ValueEventListener no onDataChange eu tento pegar os dados da Materia mas diz que esta nulo no log do Android Studio.

Acho que tem alguma coisa haver com ele recuperar uma lista dentro de materia. Não sei!!!

Alguem ajuda?

Aluno

```
public class Aluno {

    private String key;
    private String nomeAluno;
    private String materia_ref;
....
}
```

Materia

```
public class Materia {

    private String key;
    private String nomeMateria;
    private List<Aluno> alunos;
....
}
```

Activity Salva os dados:

```
public class TestandoObjetosListFirebaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseReference mReferenciaMateria;
    private DatabaseReference mReferenciaAluno;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_testando_objetos_list_firebase);

        mReferenciaMateria = ConfigurationFirebase.getDatabaseReference("materias");
        mReferenciaAluno = ConfigurationFirebase.getDatabaseReference("alunos");

        String keyMateria = mReferenciaMateria.push().getKey();

        Materia materia = new Materia();
        materia.setKey(keyMateria);
        materia.setNomeMateria("Matemetica");

        String keyAluno1 = mReferenciaAluno.push().getKey();
        Aluno aluno1 = new Aluno(keyAluno1, "Pedro", keyMateria);
        mReferenciaAluno.child(keyAluno1).setValue(aluno1);

        String keyAluno2 = mReferenciaAluno.push().getKey();
        Aluno aluno2 = new Aluno(keyAluno2, "Joaquina", keyMateria);
        mReferenciaAluno.child(keyAluno2).setValue(aluno2);

        String keyAluno3 = mReferenciaAluno.push().getKey();
        Aluno aluno3 = new Aluno(keyAluno3, "Chalaça", keyMateria);
        mReferenciaAluno.child(keyAluno3).setValue(aluno3);

        String keyAluno4 = mReferenciaAluno.push().getKey();
        Aluno aluno4 = new Aluno(keyAluno4, "Paizão", keyMateria);
        mReferenciaAluno.child(keyAluno4).setValue(aluno4);

        materia.addALunoToList(aluno1);
        materia.addALunoToList(aluno2);
        materia.addALunoToList(aluno3);
        materia.addALunoToList(aluno4);

        mReferenciaMateria.child(keyMateria).setValue(materia);

        mReferenciaMateria.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    Materia materia1 = dataSnapshot.getValue(Materia.class);
                    for(Aluno a : materia1.getAlunos()){
                        Log.i("app", a.getNomeAluno().toString());
                    }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Activity Le os dados:

```
    public class ListandoAlunosActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseReference mDBAlunos;
    private Button btListar;
    private Button btRemoverListener;
    private ListView lvAlunosPorMateria;

    private List<String> listAlunos = new ArrayList<>();

    private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapterListaAlunosPorMateria;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listando_alunos);

        btListar = findViewById(R.id.onClickButton_list_alunos);
        btRemoverListener = findViewById(R.id.onClickEncerrar_Listner);
        lvAlunosPorMateria = findViewById(R.id.lv_alunos_matriculados_materia);

        btListar.setOnClickListener(onClickListenerListarAlunosMatriculados);
        btRemoverListener.setOnClickListener(onClickListenerRemoverListener);

        mDBAlunos = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    }


    //-------------- Método que instancia o Adapter e seta no Listview
    // Método sera chamado no Listener do Firebase
    private void listaAlunosAndSetListView(){
        arrayAdapterListaAlunosPorMateria = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    listAlunos);
        lvAlunosPorMateria.setAdapter(arrayAdapterListaAlunosPorMateria);

    }


    //--------------- Click que dispara o listener ------------------------
    private View.OnClickListener onClickListenerListarAlunosMatriculados = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mDBAlunos.child("materias").child("-L6Ts6RZ9-mlgIYTifcT").child("alunos");
            mDBAlunos.addValueEventListener(listenerAlunosMatriculadosMateria);
        }
    };


    //--------------- Click para remover Listener ValueEventListener ------------------------
    private View.OnClickListener onClickListenerRemoverListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mDBAlunos.removeEventListener(listenerAlunosMatriculadosMateria);
        }
    };


    //--------------- Listener ValueEventListener ------------------------
    private ValueEventListener listenerAlunosMatriculadosMateria = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //listAlunos.clear();

            for(DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Aluno aluno = data.getValue(Aluno.class);
                listAlunos.add(aluno.getNomeAluno().toString());
            }
            listaAlunosAndSetListView();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };

}
```

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                 Process: com.hugo.escola, PID: 2782
>                                                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object
>   reference
>                                                                                     at
>   com.hugo.escola.ListandoAlunosActivity$3.onDataChange(ListandoAlunosActivity.java:86)
>                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzegf.zza(Unknown Source:13)
>                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeia.zzbyc(Unknown Source:2)
>                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeig.run(Unknown Source:65)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                     at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o erro esta aqui nesse trecho

```
private List<String> listAlunos = new ArrayList<>();
```

você esta inicializando a lista fora do método de criação, tente colocá-la dentro do onCreate.